# Position fabric.js text by baseline

Tags: fabricjs

In native HTML5 canvas the text is positioned by the text baseline but in Fabric.js it seems to be by the bottom of the text. I want Fabric.js to position text by the baseline. Is it possible?

See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbRRt.png)

This is the code used for the example.

```html
Fabric.js<br />
<canvas id="fabric" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script src="fabric.js"></script>
<script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric');
     canvas.add(new fabric.Line([100, 100, 200, 100], { left: 10, top: 50, stroke: 'red' }));
     canvas.add(new fabric.Text('Hello World', { left: 10, top: 50, originY: 'bottom', useNative: true, fontSize: 50 }));
</script>
<br /> 
Native HTML5<br />
<canvas id="native" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<script>
 var c = document.getElementById("native");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 ctx.font = "50px Times New Roman";
 ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
 
 ctx.moveTo(10,50);
 ctx.lineTo(100,50);
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
 ctx.stroke();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look possible at the moment. The textBaseline attribute is set to 'alphabetic' and the only available vertical alignment options are 'top', 'center', & 'bottom' (which are relative to the bounding box fabric draws around the text).

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2320) to request this feature.  Hopefully, they add it!